# Packer - VBox Guest Additions

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7, packer

When using packer to create a virtual box centos 7 VM does packer take care of installing the guest additions?

I have looked at several examples and one of them does the guest additions mounting and installing in the packer json file, is this necessary?

When I run the build I can see that packer takes care of downloading the guest additions but I am unsure if it installs them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't install them. That you need to take care of yourself. It will download them to the host and upload it to the guest or attach it as CD.

Comment: thanks I've written a script to assist me with that now.